# C# application crashing upon calling reflection in linked DLL

Tags: c#, reflection, disassembly

I created a DLL with reflection code in it.  When I use this DLL an application that calls the function containing the reflections calls the program crashes, and I get a null reference in the disassembled view in visual studio. However, when commenting out just the reflection calls the program runs fine.

The picture with the disassembled view I am being presented with
[click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RotDj.png)

Picture on disassembled view and stack trace [stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAvz5.png)

Below the functions I am trying to run.

```
internal static CreateInstance CreateInstanceByType(Type type)
    {
        //check constructor
        ConstructorInfo ctor = null;

        ConstructorInfo[] ctors =
            type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        for (int i = 0; i < ctors.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ctors[i].GetParameters().Length == 0)
            {
                ctor = ctors[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (ctor == null)
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(CSMInstanceFactory).GetMethod("CreateInstance");

            method = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);

            return method.CreateDelegate(typeof(CreateInstance)) as CreateInstance;
        }

        return CilCreateInstanceByType(type, ctor);
    }

    private static CreateInstance CilCreateInstanceByType(Type type, ConstructorInfo ctor)
    {
        string constructor = type.Name + ".Ctor";

        Type[] parametertypes = new Type[0];

        DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod(constructor, type, parametertypes, typeof(Activator));
        ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator(2);

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return method.CreateDelegate(typeof(CreateInstance)) as CreateInstance;
    }

    public static object CreateInstanceArrayByType(Type type, int amount)
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(CSMInstanceFactory).GetMethod("CreateInstanceArray");

        MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);

        return genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { amount });
    }
```

And below the code I commented out which resulted in it working.

```
        internal static CreateInstance CreateInstanceByType(Type type)
    {
        //check constructor
        ConstructorInfo ctor = null;

        //ConstructorInfo[] ctors =
        //    type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        //for (int i = 0; i < ctors.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    if (ctors[i].GetParameters().Length == 0)
        //    {
        //        ctor = ctors[i];
        //        break;
        //    }
        //}

        if (ctor == null)
        {
            //MethodInfo method = typeof(CSMInstanceFactory).GetMethod("CreateInstance");

            //method = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);

            //return method.CreateDelegate(typeof(CreateInstance)) as CreateInstance;
        }

        //return CilCreateInstanceByType(type, ctor);

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Show in your code which lines you comment out. Otherwise it will be difficult for someone to help.

Comment: Also please provide the full exception inclusive the stacktrace.

Comment: @kit added stacktrace and the code i commented out, keep in mind, i did comment them out bit by bit, but commenting out only all the reflection did cause it to execute the function

Comment: Unless you tell us which path the code is going though, no one can help. For example was `ctor` null? The only obvious thing is that the NRE is being thrown in your emitted code; definitely not in the emitting code.

Comment: @kit what do you mean exactly with 'the path the code is going through'

Comment: Even when I change the function to just `internal static CreateInstance CreateInstanceByType(Type type)
        {
            type.GetConstructors();

            return null;
        }` it's triggering the NRE

Comment: If you are able to step out of `CreateInstanceByType` (even with your modifications), then you might want to show/explain the calling code.